# Aws console view differs on chrome os and on windows os

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, chrome-os

I have this aws account i am using to host some apps. I have an acer laptop which has chrome os and a desktop computer which has windows os.

When i login to the aws console on chrome os, it shows me one instance running. I thought it was a simple error but i did refresh on chrome os and still displayed once instance running.

In reality i have two micro instances and one large instance running,so 3 instances are running.

On windows,i login to the console using firefox and three instances show up.

This is correct on windows.

Has anyone experienced this difference on chrome os and on windows os?.

Comment: Any chance that each browser is remembering a different region? Upper right hand corner of the console - make sure they all point to the same region.

Comment: All my instances are in US West (Oregon).